Find tension in string

Find tension in the strings
My try:
If a rod is tied with 3 light strings in different different so to find tension in all the string we need 3 equation
1 we get from dynamic equilibrium
2 we get from rotational equilibrium
From where we will get 3 equation
There must be a way to calculate the tensions in the string.
We must make a team to find the solution to this problem.
May be we can do it.
Please don't close my post I didn't get answer.
It is a serious matter

Please do not delete and repost questions. Use the edit function instead. Original question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/826894/174766

There is no unique solution. It would be possible to hang the rod using only strings 1 and 3, or with only 2 and 3, or with tension in all 3 strings, and there is no reason to prefer any of those configurations over any other.
If you hang the rod from strings 1 and 3, you can then put up string 2 with no tension, but if you hang the rod from strings 2 and 3, you can then put up string 1 with no tension. Both of these result in the same pictured apparatus, but have different tensions across the 3 strings - you cannot determine the tensions from the picture.
