How to calculate tension in this case?
I came up with this idea while learning rotational motion.
Note:
I have not found any question on it but its a concept I want to know.
Take a rod of mass M and length L. Hang it with cealing using three light strings.
(Think in two dimensions)
One attached at left end.
Second at distance x from left end.
Third at distance y from right end.
Assume no string is slack.
(Since 1 of them can be hanged without tension in it.)
Question is how we can find tension in all the strings?
My attempt:
Since we need three tensions so we must need three equations.
First I got from translation equilibrium.
Second from rotational equilibrium.
Now I wonder from where the third equation will come from.
It's not just about 3 strings. Let's say we hanged it with 4 or 5 strings so how we will be able to find all the tensions in strings?

Re: your general curiosity, you could have a look at "hyperstatic systems".

How many translational equilibrium equations did you write in 2D?

1 only possible

2D, 2 translations no?

You can just balance force in y direction which will be sum of all the tensions equal to mg

And what happens in the x-direction?

There is no force in x direction

Vote to my question please

There is no NET force in the horizontal direction.  But the individual strings can have horizontal components of force (that must cancel).

Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/826904/2451

If your three strings are non-parallel you should be able to solve for the forces independently.  But if they are all vertical or there are many more, then then you have discovered a topic called "static indeterminacy."  The usual method to augment the force balance equations is to take into account the rigidity and deflection of the components.  So your string stiffness would be inversely proportional to the length of each string (slack is possible with more than two strings), and the strings are replaced by springs.  The solution assumes load-sharing proportional to stiffness.  If you want still more precision (and complexity) you can take into account the bending deflection of the rod.  Depending on the details, you still might not be able to solve uniquely for every piece of string.
This technique allows some solutions when problems are over-constrained, however in real engineering calculations it may under-estimate individual forces by assuming ideal load sharing.  So the most conservative approach for a real world problem is to eliminate redundant supports in various combinations and calculate the worst-case loading result.

Your example is statically indeterminate, meaning one of the strings is redundant (i.e. not required for the bar to be in equilibrium).
This means the equations for static equilibrium alone are insufficient to determine the tensions in the three strings. You need to include equations related to deformation (stretching of the strings).
You need to solve this yourself since we are not allowed to provide solutions to homework and exercise type questions.
Hope this helps.
